# Undefined name 'title'. (Documentation)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**hii i am new flutter and facing following error**

```
final String title;
final String desc;
final String timer;
const ListElement({Key? key, required this.title, required this.desc ,required this.timer}) : 
super(key: key);
```

**this is my constructor in which i have passed title desc and timer**

```
 Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400 ,
                  fontSize: 30),),
 Text(desc, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400 ,
                  fontSize: 15),),
```

**while getting title and desc i am facing this error**

Comment: Can you please pull proper code for ui and model class?

Comment: please review the answer

Answer (score 1):

If your widget is `stateful` then you have to write `title` as

```
Text(widget.title, style: .......
```

Answer (score 0):

**ok i use '${widget.title}' to solve this problem**